# Recycleview scroll back to first item when calling recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position) right after recyclerView.setAdapter(mRecycleviewAdapter);

Tags: android

My app needs to adjust an item's position right after the recycleview is made visible.

**Here is my code:**

```
final RecycleviewAdapter mRecycleviewAdapter = new RecycleviewAdapter(chData, chName, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mRecycleviewAdapter);
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(desPosition);
```

After the recycleview is shown, it displays desPosition's items view first, then it scrolls back to the first item automatically. Is there anybody that has encountered the same issue?

Comment: I created a sample app here to explain the issue: 
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/kmanga/recyclerview-playground-master.zip

Comment: Actually, it's a layout problem, after putting 200p height to the item view in layout, it works as intended.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=177518&thanks=177518&ts=1434635619#makechanges